# How to add a custom item to the Microsoft Office Send To Menu

Tags: ms-office, send

Is it possible to extend the "Send to" menu in Office (not the Windows one; I know how to do that).  I would like to launch my own application with the source document as the target.

Update: I am looking for a non-VSTO based solution.

Answer (score 0):

In 2007, you can extend the ribbon, and should be able to place your control in the group `FileSendMenu` in the tab Office Menu. I don't think this is supported in the designer available in the last VSTO-addin for Visual Studio, so you may have to hand craft your xml.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="OnLoad" loadImage="OnGetImage">
  <ribbon>
    <officeMenu>
      <menu idMso="FileSendMenu">
        <button id="oButtonId"
              insertAfterMso="FileInternetFax"
              getDescription="GetDescription"
              getLabel="GetLabel"
              getScreentip="GetSuperTip"
              getSupertip="GetSuperTip"
              getVisible="GetVisible"
              onAction="OnButtonPress"/>
      </menu>
    </officeMenu>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

You will need an event handler ("OnButtonPress") as well has handlers for description, iconst etc. You could do this with VBA, but I would rather go with a proper Add-In.